# Get custom Thread's property through Runnable task

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have custom thread class which has a property. Said property passed from custom ThreadFactory. Can I somehow get that property of thread object from inside Runnable task?

example code showing the idea(may have errors):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    MyFactory factory = new MyFactory("abc");
    ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4,factory);
    MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
    e.submit(r);
}

public class MyFactory implements ThreadFactory{
    private String property;
    public MyFactory(String p){
        property = p;
    }
    public MyThread newThread(Runnable r){
        MyThread out = new MyThread(r, property);
    }
}

public class MyThread extends Thread{
    private String property;
    public MyThread(Runnable r, String p){
        super(r);
        property = p;
    }
    public String getProperty(){
        return property;
    }
}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        /* Can I get my "abc" property from >>HERE<< ? */
    {
{
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an access to the current thread inside `run` method by calling `Thread.currentThread()`. Then you just need to cast it to `MyThread`.

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
        MyThread myThread = (MyThread) Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println(myThread.getProperty());
    }
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot about type casting, that should work. Thanks for fast response, sadly I can't upvote :)